# Constraint on table to limit number of records to be stored

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a database and there are two tables `Ads` and `Images`. There is a primary key `adid` in `Ads` table which is a foreign key in `Images` table.

I want to created a constraint on table `Images` that not more than 5 `adid` can be stored in `Images` table.

I need to know what this type of constraint is called and how I can accomplish this with query in SQL Server.

Comment: In the SQL standard this can be expressed through an `assertion`. But no DBMS today supports that (Firebird supports queries for a `check` constraint which comes pretty close to an assertion). You can't express that with a simple constraint in SQL Server, you need some kind of trigger for this.

Comment: you can create UDF to check constraint and it will work.but IMHO,trigger will be best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no constaint to enforce that rule, but a trigger like the following can do it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Images_not_more_than_five_per_add
ON Images FOR INSERT
AS
DECLARE @RowCount int
SET @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF @RowCount = 1
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Images WHERE Images.addid = (SELECT addid FROM inserted)) > 5
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('No more than five images per add are allowed', 16, -1)
        ROLLBACK
        RETURN
    END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            Images
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT DISTINCT addid FROM inserted
            ) I ON Images.addid = I.addid
        GROUP BY
            Images.addid
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
    )
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('No more than five images per add are allowed', 16, -1)
        ROLLBACK
        RETURN  
    END
END
```

Answer (score 1):

The foreign key constraint doesn't have such option to limit the number of child rows.

It is possible to achieve the desired effect using a trigger, but this kind of constraint is relatively simple and it is possible to achieve the desired effect using only declarative constraints.

Create a helper table `CheckFiveRows` with column `ID` that contains five rows with values 1 to 5. `ID` is the primary key. Make sure that it contains only five rows. Add a column `CheckFiveRowID` to the `Images` table that is a foreign key pointing to `CheckFiveRows.ID`. Add unique constraint/index on `(AdID, CheckFiveRowID)`.

**Table Ads**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ads](
    [AdID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AdData] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Ads] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AdID] ASC
))
```

**Table CheckFiveRows**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CheckFiveRows](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CheckFiveRows] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
))
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CheckFiveRows] ([ID]) VALUES
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
```

**Table Images**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Images](
    [ImageID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AdID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CheckFiveRowID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ImageData] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Images] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ImageID] ASC
))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Images]  WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Images_Ads] FOREIGN KEY([AdID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Ads] ([AdID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Images] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Images_Ads]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Images]  WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Images_CheckFiveRows] FOREIGN KEY([CheckFiveRowID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CheckFiveRows] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Images] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Images_CheckFiveRows]
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CheckFiveRows] ON [dbo].[Images]
(
    [AdID] ASC,
    [CheckFiveRowID] ASC
)
GO
```

**Testing**

Populate `Ads`:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Ads] ([AdID],[AdData]) VALUES
(1, 'a1'),
(2, 'a2');

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Populate `Images`:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Images] ([ImageID],[AdID],[CheckFiveRowID],[ImageData]) VALUES
(1,1,1,'i1'),
(2,1,2,'i2'),
(3,1,3,'i3'),
(4,1,4,'i4');

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Try to add two more row for `AdID=1`:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Images] ([ImageID],[AdID],[CheckFiveRowID],[ImageData]) VALUES
(5,1,5,'i5'),
(6,1,5,'i6');

Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 8
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Images' with unique index 'IX_CheckFiveRows'. The duplicate key value is (1, 5).
The statement has been terminated.
```

Try to insert 6 rows for `AdID=2`:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Images] ([ImageID],[AdID],[CheckFiveRowID],[ImageData]) VALUES
(11,2,1,'i1'),
(12,2,2,'i2'),
(13,2,3,'i3'),
(14,2,4,'i4'),
(15,2,5,'i5'),
(16,2,6,'i6');

Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 13
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Images_CheckFiveRows". The conflict occurred in database "AdventureWorks2014", table "dbo.CheckFiveRows", column 'ID'.
The statement has been terminated.
```