# SQL set constraint on how many times a PK can be referenced

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm building a demo database of zoo for my school project and I've encountered following problem: I have a table Pavilion, which has some primary key id_pavilion and column capacity (this is information about what is the highest number of animals which can live in this pavilion).

Let's say that each pavilion can contain 2 animals at maximum.

Pavilion

```
id_pavilion   capacity
-----------------------
    1             2
    2             2
    3             2
    4             2
```

Animal

```
id_an-column2-column3    id_pavilion
---------------------------------------
   1                          2   
   2                          2   
   3                          2   
   4                          2
```

(This shows what I'm trying to prevent)

Then I have table animal, which contains some information about the animal and mainly the id_pavilion from Pavilion as a foreign key.

**My question is**: how can I add such a constraint that the PK `id_pavilion` from `Pavilion` can be referenced in table `Animal` only so many times as the capacity allows?

Comment: I believe the following _Stack Overflow_ question may be of help: [Constraint on table to limit number of records to be stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33852382/constraint-on-table-to-limit-number-of-records-to-be-stored)

Comment: Simply put, you can not. It looks like very simple question, but it really requires an expensive lock of the entire table at every update of a single row. DBMS are designed to serve multiple updates  simultaniously, and this type of constraint will prevent parallel query execution.

Comment: Write a plsql trigger on insert into `Animal` table that will throw an exception when the capacity of the pavilion is full.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your example data, one could argue that every PAVILION can accommodate 2 animals, right?  One could also say that the "accommodations" need to be in place *before* the animals can be kept in an appropriate manner.  Thus, we could create a table called ACCOMMODATION, listing all available spaces.

```
create table pavilion( id primary key, capacity )
as
select level, 2 from dual connect by level <= 4 ;

create table accommodation(
  id number generated always as identity start with 1000 primary key 
, pavilionid number references pavilion( id )
) ;
```

Generate all accommodations

```
-- No "human intervention" here.  
-- Only the available spaces will be INSERTed.
insert into accommodation ( pavilionid )
select id
from pavilion P1, lateral ( 
  select 1 
  from dual 
  connect by level <= ( select capacity from pavilion where id = P1.id )
) ;

-- we can accommodate 8 animals ...
select count(*) from accommodation ; 

  COUNT(*)
----------
         8

-- accommodations and pavilions
SQL> select * from accommodation ;

        ID PAVILIONID
---------- ----------
      1000          1
      1001          1
      1002          2
      1003          2
      1004          3
      1005          3
      1006          4
      1007          4

8 rows selected.
```

Each animal should be in a single (defined) location.  When an animal is "added" to the zoo, it can only (physically) be in a single location/accommodation.  We can use a UNIQUE key and a FOREIGN key (referencing ACCOMMODATION) to enforce this.

```
-- the ANIMAL table will have more columns eg GENUS, SPECIES, NAME etc
create table animal( 
  id number generated always as identity start with 2000
-- , name varchar2( 64 ) 
, accommodation number 
) ;

alter table animal
add (
  constraint animal_pk primary key( id )
, constraint accommodation_unique unique( accommodation )
, constraint accommodation_fk 
    foreign key( accommodation ) references accommodation( id )
);
```

Testing

```
-- INSERTs will also affect the columns GENUS, SPECIES, NAME etc
-- when the final version of the ANIMAL table is in place. 
insert into animal( accommodation ) values ( 1001 )  ;

SQL> insert into animal( accommodation ) values ( 1000 )  ;

1 row inserted.

SQL> insert into animal( accommodation ) values ( 1001 )  ;

1 row inserted.

-- trying to INSERT into the same location again 
-- MUST fail (due to the unique constraint)
SQL> insert into animal( accommodation ) values ( 1000 );
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
insert into animal( accommodation ) values ( 1000 )
Error report -
ORA-00001: unique constraint (...ACCOMMODATION_UNIQUE) violated


SQL> insert into animal( accommodation ) values ( 1001 );
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
insert into animal( accommodation ) values ( 1001 )
Error report -
ORA-00001: unique constraint (...ACCOMMODATION_UNIQUE) violated

-- trying to INSERT into a location that does not exist
-- MUST fail (due to the foreign key constraint)
SQL> insert into animal( accommodation ) values ( 9999 )  ;
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
insert into animal( accommodation ) values ( 9999 )
Error report -
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (...ACCOMMODATION_FK) violated - parent key not found
```

Animals and accommodations

```
select 
  A.id as animal
, P.id as pavilion
, AC.id as location --(accommodation)
from pavilion P
  join accommodation AC on P.id = AC.pavilionid
  join animal A on AC.id = A.accommodation
;

    ANIMAL   PAVILION   LOCATION
---------- ---------- ----------
      2000          1       1000
      2001          1       1001
```

DBfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fb9f65a117c72274d05f10176274a198).  Tested with Oracle 12c and 18c.  (You'll need version 12c+ for LATERAL join to work.)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to enforce at the database level is more of a 'business logic' rule rather than a hard data constraint. You can not implement it directly in your table designs; even if you could (as @serg mentions in the comments) it would require a very expensive (in terms of CPU/resources) lock on the table to perform the counting.

Another option, that would achieve your goal and keep the business logic separate from the data design, is to use a [SQL Trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm).

A trigger can run before the data is inserted into your table; here you can check how many rows have already been inserted for that 'pavilion entity' and abort or allow the insert.

*A comment for the "school project" side of things:*
This being said, the sort of logic you are talking about is much better served within your consuming application rather than the database (my opinion, others may disagree). Also perhaps think about defining the size limit in the data, so you can have different sized pavilions.

*Notes:*
For anyone visiting this question in the future, the above link is for an oracle trigger (as OP has tagged the question for oracle). T[his link is for Microsoft SQL Server Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Consider the task: Currently pavilion 1 hosts animals A and B, pavilion 2 hosts animals C and D. We need to move A to 2 and D to 1. Finally it's ok, but the trigger will throw at the first step. So yes, it's rather application level logic.

Comment: Seems to me that a simple check constraint (as shown in my answer) is easier to implement than a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "not easily".  Although the idea of keeping the "accommodations" in the pavilions as a separate table is a clever one, animals are put into *pavilions*, not *accommodations*.  Modeling accommodations makes it much trickier to move animals around.

Perhaps the simplest approach is to use triggers.  This starts with an `animal_count` column in `pavilions`.  This column starts at zero and is incremented or decremented as animals move in or out.  You can use a `check` constraint to validate that the pavilion is not over-capacity.

Unfortunately, maintaining this column requires triggers on the `animals` table, one for `insert`, `update`, and `delete`.

In the end, the trigger is maintaining the count and if you attempt to put an animal in a full pavilion, you will violate the `check` constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You need a column (say "NrOccupants") that is updated when an animal is placed into or removed from each pavilion. Then you add a check constraint to that column that prevents the application code from adding more animals to a pavilion than is permitted by the rule that is enforced by the check constraint.

Here is an example of the SQL DDL that would do that.

```
CREATE SCHEMA Pavilion
GO

CREATE TABLE Pavilion.Pavilion
(
    pavilionNr int NOT NULL,
    capacity tinyint CHECK (capacity IN (2)) NOT NULL,
    nrOccupants tinyint CHECK (nrOccupants IN (0, 2)) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Pavilion_PK PRIMARY KEY(pavilionNr)
)
GO


CREATE TABLE Pavilion.Animal
(
    animalNr int NOT NULL,
    name nchar(50) NOT NULL,
    pavilionNr int NOT NULL,
    type nchar(50) NOT NULL,
    weight smallint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Animal_PK PRIMARY KEY(animalNr)
)
GO


ALTER TABLE Pavilion.Animal ADD CONSTRAINT Animal_FK FOREIGN KEY (pavilionNr) REFERENCES Pavilion.Pavilion (pavilionNr) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION

GO
```